# jquery radio buttons not switching?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am confused about this code its self explanatory what its supposed to do but it doesn't do it

```
<input  name="property" type="radio" checked value="1" />Station Masters House
<input  name="property" type="radio" value="2" />Railway Carriage

<br><br>
<div id="fillin">press</div>

$("#fillin").click(function() {    
        if ($('input[name=property]').val() == "1")
        {

            alert($('input[name=property]').val());

        } else if ($('input[name=property]').val() == "2") {

            alert($('input[name=property]').val());
        }


    });
```

example here

http://jsfiddle.net/BFf5H/40/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input[name=property].length === 2` ... therefore, [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) won't work. (`.val` pulls the value of the first element in the DOM that it finds that matches the requested selector, except in the case of a `<select multiple>` element.)

Try `input[name=property]:checked` instead.

```
$("#fillin").click(function() {    
    if ($('input[name=property]:checked').val() == "1")
    {

        alert($('input[name=property]:checked').val());

    } else if ($('input[name=property]:checked').val() == "2") {

        alert($('input[name=property]:checked').val());
    }


});
```

Better yet, cache the things you need, so you are only hitting the DOM (or in this case, jQuery's cache) once:

```
$("#fillin").click(function() {
   var val = $('input[name=property]:checked').val();
    if ( val == "1") {
        alert(val);
    } else if (val == "2") {
        alert(val);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you should do

```
if ($('input[name=property]:checked').val() == "1")
```